# unable to understand Active record self join association's mathods provided by rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I want to implement a model Person where Person `has one parent` and `has_many children`. I don't want to create any other model as well .

**Person Model**

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :parent, :class_name => 'Person', :foreign_key => :parent_id
  has_many :children, :class_name => 'Person', :foreign_key => :children_id, :dependent => :destroy
end

Person(id: integer, name: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, parent_id: integer, children_id: integer)

1.9.3-p194 :024 > @a
 => #<Person id: 8, name: "a", created_at: "2015-02-10 05:53:28", updated_at: "2015-02-10 06:53:35", parent_id: nil, children_id: nil> 
1.9.3-p194 :025 > @b
=> #<Person id: 11, name: "b", created_at: "2015-02-10 06:36:31", updated_at: "2015-02-10 06:57:03", parent_id: 8, children_id: 12>
1.9.3-p194 :026 > @ab
=> #<Person id: 12, name: "ab", created_at: "2015-02-10 06:54:50", updated_at: "2015-02-10 06:54:50", parent_id: nil, children_id: nil>
```

Now `@a.parent =>`

```
Person Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "people".* FROM "people" WHERE "people"."parent_id" = $1 ORDER BY "people"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["parent_id", 8]] 

=> #<Person id: 11, name: "b", created_at: "2015-02-10 06:36:31", updated_at: "2015-02-10 06:57:03", parent_id: 8, children_id: 12>
```

**As for I know `@a` has no any `parent` because `parent_id is nil`.  then how @a.parent works.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you used two foreign keys, `parent_id` and `children_id`, so even if you destroy the link from one side the other still knows that that child/parent still exists, through the other foreign key, a basic one-to-many relationship translates into having the id on the one in the many record, so you only need `parent_id` in the child record

- The child will have the id of the parent
- The parent will not know where his children is, but to find them rails will query for all children that have a parent_id = the parent's id

Here's what you need to change in your model:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Person', foreign_key: :parent_id
  has_many :children, class_name: 'Person', foreign_key: :parent_id, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Note I replaced `has_one` with `belongs_to`, because the child has the id of the parent, not the other way around, and both use the same `parent_id` foreign key